# How to get correct value of pixel on touch in ios xamarin c#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, pixel

Hello i am trying to get the color of pixel on touch in Xamarin C#,
but i get wrong values at times,i get R=255,G=0,B=0,A=0 
What's wrong in my code?

```
 private UIColor ColorOfPoint(CGPoint point)
    {
        byte[] pixel = {0,0,0,0};

        using(CGColorSpace oColorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB())
        using(CGBitmapContext oContext = new CGBitmapContext(pixel,
                                                     1, 1, 8, 4, oColorSpace, CGBitmapFlags.PremultipliedLast & CGBitmapFlags.AlphaInfoMask))
        {
            oContext.TranslateCTM(-point.X,-point.Y);
            img.Layer.RenderInContext(oContext);
            oContext.Dispose();
            oColorSpace.Dispose();
        }

        UIColor color = new UIColor(pixel[0]/255,pixel[1]/255,pixel[2]/255,pixel[3]/255);
        return color;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIColor.FromRGBA` instead of `new UIColor(....)`

This is how I do:

```
byte[] alphaPixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
protected UIColor GetColorAtTouchPoint(CGPoint point)
{
    var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
    var bitmapContext = new CGBitmapContext(alphaPixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, CGBitmapFlags.PremultipliedLast);
    bitmapContext.TranslateCTM(-point.X, -point.Y);
    view.Layer.RenderInContext(bitmapContext);
    return UIColor.FromRGBA(alphaPixel[0], alphaPixel[1], alphaPixel[2], alphaPixel[3]);
}
```

Comment: Some strange reason causes RGB values to be returned to be 0 if you tap outside a particular area of image,Anyways thanks for the answer :)